# How to query parent child in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table structure :

```
place_id | parent_place_id |     name
---------|-----------------|------------
   1     |        2        |    child
---------|-----------------|------------
   2     |        3        |     dad
---------|-----------------|------------
   3     |                 | grandfather 
......
```

I am trying to write a query so that my output data is as follows :

```
id_Grandfather  | name_Grandfather | id_Dad | name_Dad | id_Child | name_child
----------------|------------------|--------|----------|----------|-----------
      3         |   grandfather    |   2    |   dad    |    1     |   child
```

I have tried many ways but not getting the expected result. Can anyone help me to solve it? Thank !

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with double join. But does it make any sense is totally different question.

```
SELECT
 gf.place_id as id_Grandfather,
 gf.name as name_Grandfather,
 d.place_id as id_Dad,
 d.name as name_Dad,
 c.place_id as id_Child,
 c.name as name_Child
FROM
 your_table c 
 LEFT JOIN your_table d ON c.parent_place_id = d.place_id
 LEFT JOIN your_table gf ON d.parent_lace_id = gf.place_id

-- Add this if you want to have only lines which has Dad and Grandfather fields populated
WHERE d.place_id IS NOT NULL

;
```

Comment: All my relations are in one table

Comment: Have you tried that? your_table mean one table only with alias c, d, gf.